# Is there is any compatible library for download manager to work in Android 2.2 and above?

Tags: android, android-compatibility, android-download-manager

I was downloading a video file through android app, and the DownloadManager class helped me to download easier with notification on status bar. Since the DownloadManager class is introduced in 2.3 and above am stuck with downloading functionality with notification for android 2.2. It will be very helpful for me if there is any compatible library is there for DownloadManager jus like we use support jar for fragments and other stuffs. Do you know is there any library for android download manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the system service itself didn't exist before GB. So, no, I think, sorry.

Comment: So we must write Asynctask and also customized notification for downloading functionality in android2.2

Comment: A quick [search](https://github.com/search?q=download+android&ref=cmdform) on Github shows a lot of libraries, so you're better off using one of them instead of rolling your own.